# How to Render JS and Iterate Over Array With Rails Controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a button on a view that triggers a controller action, which runs a bunch of stuff and returns and array of strings (each string is formatted as a div ex; "Hello"). I then want to take this array and add each element to the page on which the button was clicked.

Controller Method:

```
def test
    @id = params[:id]
    if @id == 'run'
        @res = Preflight.run
        respond_to do |format|
            format.js {render :js => 'run'}
        end
    else 
        render @id
    end
end
```

run.js.erb File:

```
$('#header3').show();
$('#header2').hide();
<%= puts 'made it to the js file' %>
<% @res.each do |line| %>
    $('#results').append(<%= line %>);
<% end %>
```

I know that @res is returning the array as intended, I'm unable to get the JS to trigger. Any ideas? It doesn't run the show/hide so I think the bug has to do with how I'm attempting to call the js file, but I'm unsure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: can you show us what the js looks like that's coming into your view after button press?

Comment: Do you really need to render a javascript file using erb?

Comment: We probably need the output from your browser's javascript console. How are you executing this javascript in the browser? When the ajax request returns the string of rendered javascript code, are you eval'ing it?

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the `remote: true` option in your HTML, when you call the `test` action?

Comment: No, I'm hitting it with ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that when you want to output a JS string you need to wrap it in quotes:

```
$('#results').append("<%= @res.join() %>");
```